# Reading Data from Multidomension-Array

Tags: php, json

I am quite new to PHP and try to learn with small projects for my own. And now I am struggeling.

GOAL:

- Import data from https://www.etoro.com/api/streams/v2/streams/user-trades/lee88eng
- Save "RootData:Rate, Leverage, Direction // Symbol: displayname" for the first 10 entries into variables

Problem:
I have started trying to read RootData:Rate. See attached. But getting errors.

*Warning: array_values() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in stocks_scanner/etoro.php on line 12*

Any Ideas? :-( Thanks a lot in advance! <3

````
<?php

//stock 
$stockurl = 'https://www.etoro.com/api/streams/v2/streams/user-trades/lee88eng'; // path to your JSON file
$stockdata = file_get_contents($stockurl); // put the contents of the file into a variable

$stockcharacters = json_decode($stockdata, true); // decode the JSON feed

//Array zu Variable
$timeseries = array_values($stockcharacters)['rootData'];
$close = array_values($timeseries)[0][1];
echo  "close is $close";

     
?>```
````

Comment: _403 Forbidden_  The webserver is denying access, probably because it detects that it isn't a browser.

Comment: You might be able to use https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php and include some headers.